# A term or an expression for problem-solving related strategy

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology, phrase-requests

Is there a term/expression to describe a strategy or tactic of solving biggest problem first with an expected knock-on (domino-like) effect for smaller associated problems?

Similar to Pareto (80-20) principle, but looking for something more specific and descriptive/adjectival.

Comment: I suggest you call it "the Domino Effect". Maybe this will catch on and you will become famous for it!

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts, the phrase *First things first* would be appropriate. It implies that there are other things to follow after the most important.

> used to tell someone that more important things should be done before less important things
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/first-things-first)

Comment: Excellent answer (and blindingly obvious). Some sadly go unnoticed ... for a time.

Comment: A cheering comment. I thank you. I have rather lost interest recently because so many questions seem to be closed, giving a feeling of a closed shop. Your comment reminds me to return, perhaps when the days are shorter.

Comment: Yes, a lot of questions have already been covered (at least in essence) here, and we get a lot that ELU wasn't set up for. ELU is perversely not, in the first instance, a Q & A site.